# Задание C# с помощью структур

Tags: c#

//Помогите реализовать код,чтобы пользователь мог добавлять,редактировать,удалять данные и может быть мою структуру можно правильнее записать?

```
//Создание структуры(Дата);
struct MyStruct1
{
    public DateTime MyProperty11; //public int MyProperty12; public int MyProperty13;
}
//Создание структуры(Фамилия);
struct MyStruct2
{
    public string MyProperty21; //public int MyProperty22; public int MyProperty23;
}
//Создание структуры(Имя);
struct MyStruct3
{
    public string MyProperty31; //public int MyProperty32; public int MyProperty33;
}
//Создание структуры(Описания события);
struct MyStruct4
{
    public string MyProperty41; //public int MyProperty42; public int MyProperty43;
}
//Создание структуры(Время);
struct MyStruct5
{
    public string MyProperty51; //public int MyProperty52; public int MyProperty53;
}
//Создание структуры;
struct MyStruct
{
    public MyStruct1 field1 { get; set; }
    public MyStruct2 field2 { get; set; }
    public MyStruct3 field3 { get; set; }
    public MyStruct4 field4 { get; set; }
    public MyStruct5 field5 { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStruct m = new MyStruct();
        m.field1 = new MyStruct1() { MyProperty11 = new DateTime(2019, 09, 16) };
        m.field2 = new MyStruct2() { MyProperty21 = "Пупкин"};
        m.field3 = new MyStruct3() { MyProperty31 = "Вася"};
        m.field4 = new MyStruct4() { MyProperty41 = "Купить хлеб" };
        m.field5 = new MyStruct5() { MyProperty51 = "12:45" };

        Console.WriteLine($"Дата:{m.field1.MyProperty11.ToLongDateString()} Фамилия:{m.field2.MyProperty21} Имя:{m.field3.MyProperty31} Описание события:{m.field4.MyProperty41} Время:{m.field5.MyProperty51}"); 
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: чему тут помогать, вы же сами ничего не сделали, `чтобы пользователь мог добавлять,редактировать,удалять данные`

Comment: ну наверное,я бы и не обращался за советом/помощью,если бы мог все это реализовать сам.

Comment: Я не говорю, что вы можете. Я говорю, что вы сами и не пытались себе помочь. Вы просите не помощи, вы просите чтобы кто то сделал вашу задачу за вас.

Comment: Ну не скажите,я был бы рад любой помощи,совету или примеру,т.к сам уже все перепробовал,пересмотрел и перечитал материал,но не могу понять.

Comment: ну так вы покажите, что вы перепрпобовали. Вы же в вопросе просто постановку задачи указали, а ваших попыток там нет.

Comment: Сделал уже,просто иной раз не хочется сидеть по несколько дней и делать методом проб и ошибок, хочется более быстрого результата)

Comment: это понятно, но мне, напрмер, намного приятней помогать людям, которые сами хотят что то понять, сами пытаются решить задачу, а не просто скопипастить код и выслат преподу. Потому я каждый раз прошу привести попытки, иначе помощь получается бессмысленной.

Comment: да,полностью с вами согласен,это и полезней и правильней.